# SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 on openDatabase

Tags: android, html, web-sql, opendatabase

I have a web-based Android app that uses WebSQL for storage. For some reason, calling `openDatabase` at one point (in response to a button click), causes a `DOMException` with the message `"SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"`.

Note that I am not using PhoneGap.

**The main question I'm asking here is**: What are the possible causes for a DOMException 18 on `openDatabase`?

**Some more details**:
This exception only occurs if the database does not exist yet. If it already exists, it works as expected. The function that makes the `openDatabase` call is used in another part of the app and works just fine.

**What I've tried so far**:

- Reducing the size of the database - shouldn't be an issue since it's being created by another part of the app.
- I've checked the external storage permissions - again, shouldn't be an issue.
- I read somewhere that the USB cable being plugged in could cause this issue - not what's causing it in this case.

**EDIT:**
This is what the command looks like:

```
db = openDatabase('my_database', '1.0', 'My database description', 5*1024*1024, function() {});
```

Comment: is that issue solved...i am facing the same issue...

Comment: Never found out what the cause was. In the end, I found WebSQL stability to be too inconsistent on different Android devices/versions for my needs, so I ended up writing a native interface that turned out to be far better. Though I no longer need an answer to this question, I would still be interested in hearing one, for curiosity's sake.

Comment: i solved this issue..strictly called open database inside the device ready function....

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap? (just asking to avoid confusion since the original question was non-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 2):

I found that it has to do with the allowed size of the database.
If you try to open a db that is larger than 50mb on iOS, you get this error.

Comment: While I wouldn't be surprised if opendatabase causes the exact same error if you go over the size limit, this is not the case here. Like I said, it's successfully created in another part of the app. Also, I've set the limit to 5 MB.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-opendatabase) , it cause by only two

- The user agent may raise a SECURITY_ERR exception instead of returning a Database object if the request violates a policy decision (e.g. if the user agent is configured to not allow the page to open databases).
- If origin is not a scheme/host/port tuple, then throw a SECURITY_ERR exception

Comment: Both calls have the same origin, and the user agent is configured prior to the page being loaded.

Comment: There should be something. I can figure out only if you show your code